# Ошибка в конвертации

Tags: c#

При попытке конвертировать `string` в `int` выдает ошибку:

> Ошибка    CS0029  Не удается неявно преобразовать тип "int" в "int[]".

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] str = new string[textBox1.Lines.Length];
    int[] change = new int[textBox1.Lines.Length];
    str = textBox1.Lines;
    change = Convert.ToInt32(str);
    textBox2.Text = str[0];
    textBox3.Text = Convert.ToString(change[0]);
}
```

Comment: `change = Convert.ToInt32(str);` слева - массив, справа - целое число

Comment: но у меня же объявлено что str массив строк

Comment: Ну и что? Что возвращает `Convert.ToInt32`?

Comment: Точно, с этим понятно, спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string[] str = new string[textBox1.Lines.Length];
int[] change = new int[textBox1.Lines.Length];
str[0] = textBox1.Lines[0];
change[0] = Convert.ToInt32(str[0]);
textBox2.Text = str[0];
textBox3.Text = Convert.ToString(change[0]);
```

Comment: Запустилась, но крашится на строке change[0]=Convert... C сообщением Входная строка имеет неверный формат

Comment: @Ренат Вы понимаете, что мне не видно сквозь монитор, какая строка находится в `str[0]`?

Comment: там такой текст "fastcall TForm1::Button2Click(TObject *Sender)"

Comment: @Ренат кхм, кхм, и какое целое число мы ожидаем получить из этой строки?

Comment: Понял, спасибо, просто задача стоит в том, чтобы закодировать выше указанный текст, а затем раскодировать его, хотел попробовать таким образом, можете подсказать, пожалуйста, как лучше сделать

Comment: @Ренат На эту тему следует задать другой вопрос.

Comment: Спасибо за объяснение

Comment: @Ренат Пожалуйста. Успехов! Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.